# What is the opposite of "Last updated"

Tags: terminology

I have a web site that manages issues with a building. I'd like to be able to sort the issues by

1. "Last updated" - the most recently updated issues.
2. "Opposite of last updated" - the issues that have not been updated recently.

I tried "Stale" and "Inactive" but they don't quite capture what it means to be the opposite of "Last updated".

Is there a direct opposite or should I maybe look for another way to describe "Last updated"?

Comment: This is not really appropriate here. I'll ask over at EL&U if they want it so I can migrate it.

Comment: First time this was left languishing alone.

Comment: First time this was abandoned.

Answer (score 2):

Your sort criterion is not changing for your two cases: you are always sorting on Date of Last Update, or "Last Updated" date. But one is sorted in descending order (latest date first) and the other is sorted in ascending order (earliest date first).

With a website, the usual affordance is to head the column *Last Updated On* and use a couple of arrows to choose one direction of sort or the other. You might add a note, "Most recent first" or "Oldest first". However, "oldest" might cause most people to think that it refers to the oldest **reports** rather than the least recent **update.** I suppose "Least recent first" might actually suffice.

There's no need to rename the **column** at all, and indeed there isn't an "opposite of last updated" because you are still using that data.

Comment: Thanks for the response :) the website doesn't have columns, it's a bit more like Amazon search results. Good idea though

Answer (score 1):

Last updated can contrast with

> Least recently updated

in which case, for parallelism, you might want to use

> Most recently updated

instead.